# C#: Display error code if input has more than 2 decimals

Tags: c#

I´m trying to make a program in C# that is working like a cash register and I want to make it impossibe for the user to enter a number that has more than 2 decimals = x.12 is okay but not x.123

Thank you for all answers.

EDIT: Code examples would help alot. I´m not that good at programming nor English. =)

Comment: Well, you have not mentioned as to what kind of application you are creating. I mean, would yo be taking the input from the winform, wpf, asp.net or a console application. You can implement the validation framework for validating the input, if is not Console application. You can check google for Java script validation for this requirement for asp.net. Since you do not know programming well, it is difficult to explain.

Comment: One more way I could think of it is that for this particular field, where you are getting the input, you can handle the keydown event and check for the input. Based on that, you can modify the string or show an error msg. Also, you can use Regular Expression Validator in WPF and asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

Use a NumericUpDown control to capture input and set its DecimalPlaces property to 2.

Comment: I´m new to programming so I didn´t understand what you mean. Can you show an example with code?

Answer (score 1):

You can round the decimal place to two.

```
decimal a = 1.994444;

Math.Round(a, 2);
```

Comment: I do not want the user to be able to enter anything that has more than 2 decimals therefore this solution does not help me. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

you convert the input to string and check its length(one of many solutiuons);

Example:

```
void checkLenghth()
{
    decimal value = 2.15;
    string stringDecimal = value.ToString();
    string[] splitStrings = stringDecimal.Split('.');
    if (splitStrings[1] > 3)
    MessageBox("Its wrong!"); 
}
```

this is just an orientation example, i am not saying it must be implemented exactly like that (for critics :) )

Comment: ... so your system will be limited to amounts less than 10? The value "10.01" would for instance be invalid using this logic.

Comment: its not limited to anything , its just an example, of course critics are said to rise even from the grave. You can use a string.split to check just the part after the dot now, can you not?

Comment: If you're gonna offer some advice in the first place, even if it's "just an example", it should at least be minimally sane. And checking to see if a number has only (or max) two digits after the decimal separator by checking the _total_ length of the number's string representation, isn't something one should be teaching. Especially not to beginners, who obviously doesn't know much about programming.

Comment: and your better suggestion is? and i thought its minimally sane (huge lol) altough not all of us are super programmers like you (hope you posses a sense of humour). Whats so insane about checking its string representation?

Comment: Checking the _total_ length of the string representation is pretty insane, because of the reason suggested in my first comment. Using ´String.Split´, as you suggested in a comment yourself, to make sure you only count the digits _after_ the decimal separator, would be a step in the right direction (and if you change your answer to this, that would of course remove the down vote). And _yes_, I do have a sense of humor, and _no_, I'm no super programmer (of course that's a joke (good humor!), because I really _am_ a super programmer (joking again... I could keep going like this for ever...)) ;-)

Comment: I am sure if I understand this correct, but the question states that the user should not be able to enter a decimal no with more than 2 digits after the decimal. What you are doing here is checking input after it has been entered. Where as the requirement is to restrict the input itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the input using a regular expression. The example below requires the input to consist of at least one digit, optionally followed by a decimal place followed by 1 or 2 extra digits:

```
string number = "1.23";
bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(number, @"^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$");
```